# QT Webkit & OpenGL Rendering Context

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

Would it be possible to create a window with a webpage using a webkit component using QT4, then embed an OpenGL context into the middle in the same way a java applet or a flash applet may appear normally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can embed any QWidget into a web page shown through a QWebView, including a QGLWidget. This would be a starting point in the docs: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qwebpage.html#setPluginFactory .

Comment: I gogoled using the references you mentioned and it lead me to this: http://daniel-albuschat.blogspot.com/2008/12/embedding-qt-widgets-into-qtwebkit.html ^_^ Since you gave me the lead I needed Ill accept the answer thanks!